# Cant make "path" into type real

Tags: cocoa, unix, applescript

I have a script file inside the "Resources" folder, I am trying to run it like this

```
set scriptpath to (path to current application as text)
set scripty to do shell script scriptpath/Contents/Resources/moveskript & variable1 & variable2 with administrator privileges
```

But it tells me this:

```
2015-12-01 12:19:47.208 Move[16404:534222] *** -[AppDelegate mybuttonhandler:]: Can’t make "(path.app):" into type real. (error -1700)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- You're mixing up HFS paths (colon separated) and POSIX paths (slash separated)
- `current application` is the current AppleScript runner, not the current script / application.

Use Cocoa methods to get the path to the resources folder.

```
set resourceFolder to current application's NSBundle's mainBundle's resourcePath()
set scriptpath to (resourceFolder's stringByAppendingPathComponent:"moveskript") as text
set scripty to do shell script quoted form of scriptpath & space & quoted form of variable1 & space & quoted form of variable2 with administrator privileges
```

Consider that shell parameters must be separated by space characters (between `scriptpath` and `variable1` and between `variable1` and `variable2`) and space characters within parameters must be escaped.

Comment: I mixed them up because I wasn't able to run `set scripty to do shell script "scriptpath..."` because It didn't read `scriptpath` as a variable then. But with your script, I instead get this:

`2015-12-01 13:41:16.501Move[39067:617575] *** -[AppDelegate mybuttonhandler:]: Can’t make «class ocid» id «data optr000000004014020000600000» into type constant. (error -1700)`

Comment: I understand, you're talking about an AppleScriptObjC application. The `«class ocid»` error occurs when you're passing a Cocoa object to AppleScript. You have to coerce it to something AppleScript understands. Of what kind is `variable1` and `variable2`?

Comment: @vadlan They are both paths that come from cocoa Text Fields.

Comment: They are defined like this `set variable1 to textField's stringValue() as text`.

Comment: AppleScript doesn't know `NSString`, you have to coerce them to AppleScript text:  `(variable1 as text)` / `(variable2 as text)` and if they contain space or other special characters you have to escape them like  `quoted form of (variable1 as text)`. And don't forget the space separators if necessary.

Comment: `set scripty to do shell script scriptpath & (variable1 as text) & (variable2 as text) with administrator privileges` still produce the same error. And it has worked before, if i replace the "scriptpath/Contents/Resources/moveskript" with just echo, it will echo the paths just fine.

Comment: Could you please add s sample how the entire string you pass to the shell looks like.

Comment: '/Users/admin' is an example.

Comment: please the entire string.

Comment: What do you mean? That is the entire string, literally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96681/discussion-between-vadian-and-displayname).

Comment: This is more of a critique of the code in general, and does not answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this part:

```
... do shell script scriptpath/Contents/Resources/moveskript ...
```

To concatenate a literal string to a variable, you need wrap the string in quotes and use `&`:

```
do shell script scriptpath & "/Contents/Resources/moveskript"
```

Because the slashes aren't within quotes, Applescript recognizes them as a division symbol, so it thinks you are trying to divide `scriptpath` by `Contents`. That is why it is trying to coerce the `scriptpath` variable into type `real`. But, since it's a string with letters, Applescript is unable to convert it.

Comment: I always thought this but I didn't know how to use a variable in that case, but turns out it's as usual.